# 16.04 Gnome Software PPA applications

Tags: ppa, 16.04, gnome-software

With the new Gnome Software replacing Ubuntu Software Center, will I still be able to add PPAs and have those app show up in Gnome Software?

Comment: It depends on whether these ppa have packages for `xenial`.

Comment: And you can still use Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It depends on each app in particular. Y-ppa-manager shows correctly in GSC. Wine does not. I have currently Wine 1.8 installed, but GSC shows only Wine 1.6 available... to install. OpenJDK 9 comes preinstalled, and yet GSC won't recognize it, no listing of any version AT ALL. WPS Office shows correctly in GSC, but will not provide updates because there is no ppa for it. Make sure you always use the correct ppa! It should work. Most of the times.